# How to Execute Stored Procedure using Async in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
await _database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"EXECUTE PROCEDURE {procedureName}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for the issue

```
public async Task ExecuteStoredProcedure(string procedureName){   
   //await _database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(procedureName);  
   //await _database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"EXECUTE PROCEDURE{procedureName}");

               using (var command = _database.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
               {
                   if (_database.Database.GetDbConnection().State != ConnectionState.Open)
                       _database.Database.GetDbConnection().Open();

                   command.CommandText = procedureName;
                   command.CommandTimeout = 600;
                   try
                   {
                       await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                   }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {

                       throw e;
                   }
               }

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public async Task DoWork()
{
    using(var context = new SampleContext())
    {
        var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC AddCategory @CategoryName", 
        name);
    }
}
```